# Restoring a MS SQL Server database on Linux

Tags: sql-server, restore, linux

I am running Manjaro Linux and I am trying to restore a Microsoft SQL Server database from a `.bak` file.

I am trying to follow [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-backup-and-restore-database?view=sql-server-ver15#restore-a-database), but it doesn't seem to work!

```
➜  ~ sudo sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [bejebeje] FROM DISK = N'/home/jwan/Dropbox/projects/personal/bejebeje/backups/2018-04-13/BejebejeDb2018-04-13.bak' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, NORECOVERY, STATS =5"
[sudo] password for jwan: 
Password: 
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Server jwan-pc, Line 1
Cannot open backup device '/home/jwan/Dropbox/projects/personal/bejebeje/backups/2018-04-13/BejebejeDb2018-04-13.bak'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server jwan-pc, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
```

I also tried without the `sudo` and I got the same thing. What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I tried the suggestion in the comments, and it still didn't work, here's what I got:

```
➜  ~ sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [bejebeje] FROM DISK = N'/home/jwan/sqlbackup/BejebejeDb2018-04-13.bak' WITH FILE = 1, NOUNLOAD, REPLACE, NORECOVERY, STATS =5" 
Password: 
Msg 3201, Level 16, State 2, Server jwan-pc, Line 1
Cannot open backup device '/home/jwan/sqlbackup/BejebejeDb2018-04-13.bak'. Operating system error 2(The system cannot find the file specified.).
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server jwan-pc, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
➜  ~ ls -l sqlbackup
total 5720
-rwxrwxrwx 1 jwan jwan 5854720 Apr 15  2018 BejebejeDb2018-04-13.bak
➜  ~
```

Comment: Comments archived in [this chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124214/discussion-on-question-by-j86-restoring-a-ms-sql-server-database-on-linux).

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit the script (/opt/mssql/lib/mssql-conf/mssql-conf.py) using text editor, It is line 1: #!/usr/bin/python22, which may be wrong.

I changed it #!/usr/bin/python2 
Plz try this

Comment: I did this when I installed `mssql-server` this isn't my issue though, as now I already have `/python2` on that script.